# How to filter JSON based on search using React?

Tags: reactjs, json

I have Json and I stored that in some state, and i'm rendering that JSON using map function,

So now my question is how to filter json based on serach result,

Here is the setState

```
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState([]);
```

This is the JSON

const JSON=[

```
   {
       "name":"compoundName",
        "id":"1",
       "hierarchy":[
          {
             "order":1,
             "displayName":"Study",
             "count":26,
             "width":"auto/10%/100px",
             "childern":[
                {
                   "id":100,
                   "displayName":"Clinical-Trail-1",
                   "color":"red",
                   "forward":[
                      {
                         "id":1,
                         "displayName":"FG-1",
                         "blockColor":"red",
                         "arrowColor":"blue"
                      },
                      {
                        "id":1,
                        "displaName":"FG-2",
                        "blockColor":"red",
                        "arrowColor":"blue"
                     }
                   ],
                   "backward":[
                     
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":101,
                   "displayName":"Clinical-Trail-2",
                   "color":"red",
                   "forward":[
                      
                   ],
                   "backward":[
                     
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":102,
                   "displayName":"Clinical-Trail-3",
                   "color":"red"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "order":2,
             "displayName":"Finish Goods",
             "count":26,
             "width":"auto/10%/100px",
             "childern":[
                {
                   "id":100,
                   "displayName":"FG-1",
                   "color":"green",
                   "forward":[
                      {
                         "id":1,
                         "displayName":"PG-1",
                         "blockColor":"red",
                         "arrowColor":"blue"
                      },
                      {
                        "id":1,
                        "displayName":"PG-3",
                        "blockColor":"red",
                        "arrowColor":"blue"
                     }
                   ],
                   "backward":[
                      {
                         "id":1,
                         "displayName":"Clinical-Trail-1",
                         "blockColor":"red",
                         "arrowColor":"blue"
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":101,
                   "displayName":"FG-2",
                   "color":"green"
                },
                {
                   "id":102,
                   "displayName":"FG-3",
                   "color":"green"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "order":3,
             "displayName":"Primary Goods",
             "count":26,
             "width":"auto/10%/100px",
             "childern":[
                {
                   "id":100,
                   "displayName":"PG-1",
                   "color":"indigo",
                   "forward":[
                    {
                       "id":1,
                       "displayName":"BG-1",
                       "blockColor":"red",
                       "arrowColor":"blue"
                    },
                    
                   
                 ],
                 "backward":[
                    {
                       "id":1,
                       "displayName":"FG-1",
                       "blockColor":"red",
                       "arrowColor":"blue"
                    }
                 ]
                },
                {
                   "id":101,
                   "displayName":"PG-2",
                   "color":"indigo"
                },
                {
                   "id":102,
                   "displayName":"PG-3",
                   "color":"indigo",
                   "forward":[],
                   "backward":[
                    {
                       "id":1,
                       "displayName":"FG-1",
                       "blockColor":"red",
                       "arrowColor":"blue"
                    }
                 ]
                },
                {
                    "id":102,
                    "displayName":"PG-4",
                    "color":"indigo"
                 }
             ]
          },
          {
             "order":4,
             "displayName":"Bulk Goods",
             "count":26,
             "width":"auto/10%/100px",
             "childern":[
                {
                   "id":100,
                   "displayName":"BG-1",
                   "color":"#aa00ff",
                   "forward":[
                    {
                       "id":1,
                       "displayName":"AP-1",
                       "blockColor":"red",
                       "arrowColor":"blue"
                    }],
                    "backward":[
                       {
                          "id":1,
                          "displayName":"PG-1",
                          "blockColor":"red",
                          "arrowColor":"blue"
                       }
                    ]
                },
                {
                   "id":101,
                   "displayName":"BG-2",
                   "color":"#aa00ff"
                },
                {
                   "id":102,
                   "displayName":"BG-3",
                   "color":"#aa00ff"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "order":5,
             "displayName":"APIs",
             "count":26,
             "width":"auto/10%/100px",
             "childern":[
                {
                   "id":100,
                   "displayName":"AP-1",
                   "color":"#e2448b",
                   "forward":[
                   
                 ],
                 "backward":[
                    {
                       "id":1,
                       "displayName":"BG-1",
                       "blockColor":"red",
                       "arrowColor":"blue"
                    }
                 ]
                },
                {
                   "id":101,
                   "displayName":"AP-2",
                   "color":"#e2448b"
                },
                {
                   "id":102,
                   "displayName":"AP3-3",
                   "color":"#e2448b"
                },
                {
                    "id":102,
                    "displayName":"AP3-4",
                    "color":"#e2448b"
                 }
             ]
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "name":"compoundName-2",
       "id":"2",
       "hierarchy":[
          {
             
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
```

So suppose if I search **Clinical-Trail-1** I want result should be like this

```
 const JSON=[
    {
       "name":"compoundName",
        "id":"1",
       "hierarchy":[
          {
             "order":1,
             "displayName":"Study",
             "count":26,
             "width":"auto/10%/100px",
             "childern":[
                {
                   "id":100,
                   "displayName":"Clinical-Trail-1",
                   "color":"red",
                   "forward":[
                      {
                         "id":1,
                         "displayName":"FG-1",
                         "blockColor":"red",
                         "arrowColor":"blue"
                      },
                      {
                        "id":1,
                        "displaName":"FG-2",
                        "blockColor":"red",
                        "arrowColor":"blue"
                     }
                   ],
                   "backward":[
                     
                   ]
                },
             ]
          },
          {
             "order":2,
             "displayName":"Finish Goods",
             "count":26,
             "width":"auto/10%/100px",
             "childern":[
                {
                   "id":100,
                   "displayName":"FG-1",
                   "color":"green",
                   "forward":[
                      {
                         "id":1,
                         "displayName":"PG-1",
                         "blockColor":"red",
                         "arrowColor":"blue"
                      },
                      {
                        "id":1,
                        "displayName":"PG-3",
                        "blockColor":"red",
                        "arrowColor":"blue"
                     }
                   ],
                   "backward":[
                      {
                         "id":1,
                         "displayName":"Clinical-Trail-1",
                         "blockColor":"red",
                         "arrowColor":"blue"
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":101,
                   "displayName":"FG-2",
                   "color":"green"
                },
                {
                   "id":102,
                   "displayName":"FG-3",
                   "color":"green"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "order":3,
             "displayName":"Primary Goods",
             "count":26,
             "width":"auto/10%/100px",
             "childern":[
                {
                   "id":100,
                   "displayName":"PG-1",
                   "color":"indigo",
                   "forward":[
                    {
                       "id":1,
                       "displayName":"BG-1",
                       "blockColor":"red",
                       "arrowColor":"blue"
                    },
                    
                   
                 ],
                 "backward":[
                    {
                       "id":1,
                       "displayName":"FG-1",
                       "blockColor":"red",
                       "arrowColor":"blue"
                    }
                 ]
                },
                {
                   "id":101,
                   "displayName":"PG-2",
                   "color":"indigo"
                },
                {
                   "id":102,
                   "displayName":"PG-3",
                   "color":"indigo",
                   "forward":[],
                   "backward":[
                    {
                       "id":1,
                       "displayName":"FG-1",
                       "blockColor":"red",
                       "arrowColor":"blue"
                    }
                 ]
                },
                {
                    "id":102,
                    "displayName":"PG-4",
                    "color":"indigo"
                 }
             ]
          },
          {
             "order":4,
             "displayName":"Bulk Goods",
             "count":26,
             "width":"auto/10%/100px",
             "childern":[
                {
                   "id":100,
                   "displayName":"BG-1",
                   "color":"#aa00ff",
                   "forward":[
                    {
                       "id":1,
                       "displayName":"AP-1",
                       "blockColor":"red",
                       "arrowColor":"blue"
                    }],
                    "backward":[
                       {
                          "id":1,
                          "displayName":"PG-1",
                          "blockColor":"red",
                          "arrowColor":"blue"
                       }
                    ]
                },
                {
                   "id":101,
                   "displayName":"BG-2",
                   "color":"#aa00ff"
                },
                {
                   "id":102,
                   "displayName":"BG-3",
                   "color":"#aa00ff"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "order":5,
             "displayName":"APIs",
             "count":26,
             "width":"auto/10%/100px",
             "childern":[
                {
                   "id":100,
                   "displayName":"AP-1",
                   "color":"#e2448b",
                   "forward":[
                   
                 ],
                 "backward":[
                    {
                       "id":1,
                       "displayName":"BG-1",
                       "blockColor":"red",
                       "arrowColor":"blue"
                    }
                 ]
                },
                {
                   "id":101,
                   "displayName":"AP-2",
                   "color":"#e2448b"
                },
                {
                   "id":102,
                   "displayName":"AP3-3",
                   "color":"#e2448b"
                },
                {
                    "id":102,
                    "displayName":"AP3-4",
                    "color":"#e2448b"
                 }
             ]
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "name":"compoundName-2",
       "id":"2",
       "hierarchy":[
          {
             
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
```

How do I do this, could some one please give me the suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to find all the items where at least one of the `studies` objects has a `compound` with value "ClinicalTrail-1"? Or are you wanting to search all values in all the objects for some string?

Comment: @seesharper, Hi i edited the JSON structure could you please check it

Comment: Well it's completely different from what you had before, which makes the answer also totally different. But my question is still, are you wanting a general search, i.e. to filter by *any* field in any object in the array, or do you just want to search on some specific field or fields?

Comment: @seesharper , I want specific object to be filter out, and rest sould be same as it is.And JSON should again set to treeData

Comment: could someone please suggest me the solution for this

Comment: It's totally unclear - that's why I haven't answered and no-one else has either. You need to be *precise* about the requirement. It seems some items were left in because backward array contained the value you were filtering on? What arrays and keys need to be filtered EXACTLY?